# How do I display an list of messages from Firebase in an Android TextView?

Tags: java, android, firebase

So I have a very simple array in Firebase shown here:

[image: Firebase Array]

I want to be able to display those messages in a textview and add to the textview when a new message is added to the array. My code to display the messages is shown here:

```
        myFirebaseRef.child("messages").child("message").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            GenericTypeIndicator<List<String>> t = new GenericTypeIndicator<List<String>>() {};
            List<String> messages = snapshot.getValue(t);
            if( messages == null ) {
                System.out.println("No Messages");
            }
            else {
                for(int i = 0; i < messages.size(); i++) {
                    messageDisplay.setText(messageDisplay.getText() + "\n" + messages.get(i) + "\n");
                }
            }
        }
```

This is not working as expected and I am getting a "failed to bounce to type" exception on the GenericTypeIndicator. Any idea where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What looks like an array to you, looks like an *associative* array to Firebase. The difference is subtle but important, because it means you cannot deserialize the JSON into a `List<String>`. Instead if should likely be a `Map<String,String>`.

But the following approach is a lot simpler and better:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.getChildrenCount() == 0) {
        System.out.println("No Messages");
    } 
    else {
        for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            String message = messageSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            messageDisplay.setText(messageDisplay.getText() + "\n" + message + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```